# Prove that a funtion is differentiable at zero

Tags: functions, derivatives

Prove that for a function $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and for it holds that $\mid f(x) \mid\le x^2$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable in $0$ and that $f'(0)=0$.

From the domen and $\mid f(x) \mid\le x^2$ we can get that $\mid f(x) \mid < 1$, so $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow (-1,1)$.

Comment: Note that $f(0)=0$

Comment: So I just have to prove that the function is differentiable in 0? After that we have from $f(0)=0$ by taking the derivative of both sides that $f'(0)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

DiegoMath already comment that $f(0)=0$. Now ,$$|f'(0)|=\lim_{h\to 0}\left|\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\right|=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|f(h)|}{h}\le\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^2}{h}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(0)=0$, because $|f(0)|\leq0$.

Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}.$$

But, for $x\neq0$ we have 
$$\frac{|f(x)|}{|x|}\leq|x|.$$

Appling limit in both sides of the last inequality we have done!